# Add text on image and retrive memory back

Tags: c++, image-processing, jpeg, gdi+

Currently I use this simple library [ImageStone](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13559/ImageStone?fid=284018&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=151#xx0xx/) for writing text on image purpose.
I really need to get jpeg (data as memory) at the end of the end of the image processing because I need to send it via socket.
I don't know much about Image libraries such as this and about gdi+ also. I just need to add some informations to my screenshot thats all. If you know a better solution or another library which will convert my image back into jpeg and will retrieve memory back.
In 2 words: Just need add text on jpeg image( as data ) and need to back to jpeg format ( as data too ).

```
void DrawTextImage(HDC dc)
{
    // GDI draw text
    SetTextColor(dc, RGB(0, 0, 255));
    TextOutA(dc, 0, 0, "SampleText", 10);

    // GDI+ draw text
    Gdiplus::Graphics   g(dc);
    g.SetSmoothingMode(Gdiplus::SmoothingModeAntiAlias);
    g.SetInterpolationMode(Gdiplus::InterpolationModeHighQualityBicubic);

    Gdiplus::FontFamily   ffami(L"Arial");
    Gdiplus::StringFormat fmt;

    Gdiplus::GraphicsPath   str_path;
    str_path.AddString(L"Sample Text", -1, &ffami, Gdiplus::FontStyleBold, 48, Gdiplus::Point(20, 20), &fmt);

    Gdiplus::Pen   gp(Gdiplus::Color::Black, 8);
    gp.SetLineJoin(Gdiplus::LineJoinRound);

    Gdiplus::Rect    rc(20, 20, 30, 60);
    Gdiplus::Color   cStart(255, 255, 255);
    Gdiplus::Color   cEnd(0, 128, 255);
    Gdiplus::LinearGradientBrush  gb(rc, cStart, cEnd, Gdiplus::LinearGradientModeVertical);

    g.DrawPath(&gp, &str_path);
    g.FillPath(&gb, &str_path);
}
void SendScreenShot(const void *buffer, int size)
{
    TCPSocketConnection FileServer;
    EndPoint ServerAddress;
    char *memory;
    file_struct data;
    data.size = size;

    memory = new char[size];
    memcpy(memory, buffer, size);

    //time_t czas;
    //time(&czas);
    //asctime(localtime(&czas));

    Image.Load(memory, size, IMG_JPG);
    DrawTextImage(FCImageDrawDC(Image));

    FileServer.Connect(Addon->GetAddress(), Addon->GetPort() + 1);

    FileServer.Send((char *) &data, sizeof(file_struct));
    Sleep(500);
    // need to convert back to jpeg raw data here
    FileServer.SendAll((char *)buffer, size);
    FileServer.Close();
    delete memory;
    Image.Destroy();
}
```

Comment: where is memory deleted?

Comment: This is just a piece of code, don't worry about it.

Comment: after all, you can add this to your sample, this doesn't hurt

Comment: Sorry, dont get me wrong. Just thought about to make it simpler.

Comment: no problem about this, thank you